# Adding or subtracting the value of a field in a SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Here's a query I have:

```
SELECT
    C.CLIENTNUMBER,
    (SELECT SUM(B.FEES) WHERE B.TYPE IN ('1', '2')) AS TOTALFEES
FROM CLIENTS C
INNER JOIN BILLS B ON B.CLIENTNUMBER = C.CLIENTNUMBER
GROUP BY C.CLIENTNUMBER
```

This is pretty straightforward, but here's the rub. If `B.TYPE` is either 1 or 2, I want to add `B.FEES` to `TOTALFEES`. But if it's 3, I want to subtract `B.FEES` from `TOTALFEES`.

Any ideas on how to do this ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT C.CLIENTNUMBER,
       SUM(case when B.TYPE IN ('1', '2') 
                then B.FEES
                else -B.FEES 
           end) AS TOTALFEES
FROM CLIENTS C
INNER JOIN BILLS B ON B.CLIENTNUMBER = C.CLIENTNUMBER
GROUP BY C.CLIENTNUMBER
```

This sums up all `B.FEES` but with a condition in the `case`: Add `B.FEES` to the sum if `B.TYPE IN ('1', '2')`, otherwise subtract `B.FEES`.